# What does this mean "to bring up somebody with somebody else"

Tags: meaning

"I brought up Nikki with Scott and he blanked me. Ironic considering."

Scott from the band the Waterboys wrote a song about Nikki Sudden (or supposed to be about Nikki Sudden) . When Scott was asked about it .....

bring up somebody with somebody else, what does it mean? : may be  spoken  and he blanked me (did not answer, ignore me) is it slang ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, to mention someone in a conversation with someone else.

Comment: By the way, you can also “bring up” other topics, not just other people during conversation.

Answer (score 1):

To bring up [somebody or something] with [another person] can mean to mention, or start to talk about, that person or thing to the other person. Somebody asked Scott about Nikki and Scott ignored the person who asked ('blanked' him or her).

> bring sth up
> phrasal verb with bring
> verb [ T ]
> to start to talk about a particular subject:
> *Nobody was willing to bring up the subject of pay at the meeting.*

[Bring something up (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bring-sth-up)

> blank verb
> informal UK
> (IGNORE)   [
> [ T ]
> mainly UK
> to ignore someone or pretend that you have not seen them or do not know them:
> *When I saw him out at a club the next night, he blanked me.*

[Blank (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blank)